# Can MongoDB manage balancing between the Mongos Dynamically using TCP Balancer

Tags: mongodb, master-slave-replication, mongodb-3.4

If I have a business where I maintain 10 applications and I need to divide the request load of these 10 applications between 3 Mongos Dynamically.

Like the TCP Loadbalancer need to connect to MongoDB config servers and taking the Health status of 3 Mongos constantly and distributing the request load from application depending on the health state(getting to whether a particular Mongos is busy or free).

Is anything like the above can be achieved using TCP Balancer? or Its just can be used to configure the load static.

Please, confirm.

Answer (score 0):

If those (10) applications are at own nodes (you have multiple application nodes), every node can have mongos installed, so application Connect's localhost mongos. Those mongos then connect's to your config servers and cluster.

You just use LB to distribute client load to those application servers.

Answer (score 0):

No. An external TCP Load Balancer (in front of mongos) is not supported by MongoDB. Place the mongos router on each application server. In front of application server you can have TCP LB.

> First, a mongos acts like a router in front of a partitioned system. A
>   driver, the name for mongodb’s client, will connect to a mongos and
>   let it handle which partition to route a CRUD operation. This works
>   extremely well. MongoDB has a number of different drivers for
>   different languages and frameworks.
>
> Second, for queries whose results are larger than a single batch, a
>   cursor is created. It is basically a correlating identifier for a
>   number of batches in a driver. A driver issues a query (OP_QUERY) and
>   receives the first batch of results. If the response from the OP_QUERY
>   included a cursor id, it means there are more results and a driver can
>   issue an OP_GET_MORE to retrieve the next batch. The only requirement
>   here is that the OP_GET_MORE be issued to the same server that
>   received it initially. Reason
>
> So, what is the problem? Well, given that a load balancer has been
>   placed in front of a bunch of different servers, and that mongodb
>   requires OP_GET_MOREs to be sent to the same server as the initial
>   OP_QUERY, the load balancer would be required to understand the
>   MongoDB wire protocol to guarantee this behavior. The problem is, of
>   course, that load balancers don’t understand the MongoDB wire
>   protocol. So, simply put, load balancing mongos’ simply won’t work,
>   right?

[Load Balancing Mongos](http://craiggwilson.com/2013/10/21/load-balanced-mongos/)